# Jquery show sub menu on click for responsive site

Tags: submenu, jquery

I'm using a script that prepends a menu-icon at the top of my page for the mobile version of a responsive website. I am combining 2 horizontal navbars (one at top of page and one further down) into one vertical menu with submenus. That part works perfectly.

I want to add one more feature, though, which is to hide the sub-menus until parent is clicked - that way the initial mobile menu won't be so long. There's 3 out of 10 top-level links that have sub-menus. Those three are live links themselves, not placeholders. So I need the sub-menus to open and have both the parent and children be clickable.

Here's the jquery that shows the entire menu on click in the mobile version of the site:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
/* prepend menu icon */
$('#topwrap').prepend('<div id="menu-icon"></div>');

/* toggle nav */
$("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
$("#topnav,#mainnav").slideToggle();
$(this).toggleClass("active");

});
});
```

Here's the CSS for the mobile version of the menu:

```
#menu-icon {
display: block;
float: right;
width: 65px;height: 62px;
margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
background-image: url(images/menuicon.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: right top;
}
#topnav {display:none;
z-index: 50; 
position: absolute; 
top:110px; 
right:30px;
background-color: #fff5b9;width: 70%; height: auto;
margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
padding: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
border-top: 2px solid #8e9360;
border-right: 2px solid #8e9360;
border-left: 2px solid #8e9360;
 text-decoration: none; 
 }
#topnav li {
margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
list-style: none;
}

#mainnav {
display: none;
z-index: 50;
position: absolute; 
top:320px; 
right:30px;
background-color: #fff5b9;width: 70%; margin: -10px auto 10px auto;
padding: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
border-right: 2px solid #8e9360;
border-left: 2px solid #8e9360;
border-bottom: 2px solid #8e9360;
text-decoration: none;
}
#mainnav li {margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
padding: 10px 0;
list-style: none;
}
#mainnav ul ul {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

#topnav a, #mainnav a {text-decoration: none;
font: 600 14px/14px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color: #1e320d;}
```

The html is standard nested ul, li, ul, li

I want to include the script in the mobilemenu.js script or in same document as I need it only to apply to the sub-menus in the mobile version of the site.

I'm an HTML/CSS person who's good at cutting a pasting php and js/jquery but not writing js/jquery or php. Site is built in WordPress and I'm still styling and tweaking the theme and there's no content yet, but you can see it live at

```
http://64.17.148.68/
```

Submenus for Camping, Cabins and River Trips

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// first hide all submenus
$(".sub-menu").hide();

// add click handler to links you know have a submenu
$("a:contains('Camping'), a:contains('Cabins'), a:contains('River Trips')").click(
    // find next submenu and show/hide it
    $(this).parent("li").next(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
);
```

It's not tested and I'm pretty sure it's not working :), but should put you in the right path.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for responding. Haven't gotten this to work - my mobile menu disappears completely -- but I'll keep trying.